# Camera upload on wp8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, background-task

On windows phone 8 we have the ability to register a ResourceIntensiveTask as an 'auto-upload' extension. Which enables it to perform resource intensive tasks (uploading all your photo's) for an unlimited amount of time (ofcourse under very strict conditions).

Now I'm trying to port my app to windows phone 8.1 (not the silverlight flavor) and I can't seem to find how to achieve the same functionality. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Background task in windows phone 8.1 RT is different than in Silverlight. Watch below video for details on Background task in windows phone RT

[Background Tasks and Multitasking](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/11)

Comment: It's a good video, but I already found all this stuff. There is no mention of anything close to the resourceintensive task

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Runtime background processing model is more nuanced and flexible than the one provided for Windows Phone Silverlight apps, so there isn't a direct equivalent of the resource intensive task. To mimic the conditions under which resource intensive tasks are launched, you could register for the [MaintenanceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ883699%28v=win.10%29.aspx) (which only runs on AC power) and set a [SystemConditionType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemconditiontype.aspx) to require a free (ie. Wifi) network.

One thing you should consider is whether you really need to perform the uploads yourself. If the [BackgroundUploader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx) class can meet your needs, you could use a [TimeTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059.aspx) to poll the camera roll periodically and then add uploads to the background upload queue. This allows the system to manage the uploads on your behalf.